# How to get datas from multiple sheet to userform textboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform where i have to get datas from few sheets to the textboxes in userform. My coding is only tranfering datas from the active sheet.

I have a multipage in my userform where page1(part info) with 7 textboxes and page 2(stock info)with 5 textboxes. All this textboxes are to populate information from excel sheets.

Once I key in the partno in textbox1, all the textboxes in multipage must auto populate. I've got no issues with getting data for page 1 cause all the datas in page1 comes from sheet 1(part details).

But in page 2 i need data's from:

- sheet4(stock update) for textbox12,
- sheet3(shipment update) for textbox13,
- sheet2(rejection update) for textbox14,

Please check my codes and advice me what are the changes i must do.

Thanks.

Below are my codes and userform pics.

```
Sub GetData()
    '--------------------------------------
    ' Check database for entry in Textbox1 _
     and if in DB then populate other TB _
     and image
    '--------------------------------------

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim wsData1 As Worksheet
    Dim shImage As Shape
    Dim sID As String
    Dim wsData2 As Worksheet

    Set wsData1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Part Details")     
    With wsData1
       ' Get the item number in sID
        sID = Me.TextBoxs1.Value
        ' check column A of the datasheet for the entry
        Set rFound = Columns("A").Find(what:=sID, _
                                    after:=.Cells(1, 1))
        ' if found, process. else quit
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then ' This checks that rFound is set to an object and not 'nothing'
            ' Load the details in the text boxes
            For j = 2 To 11
                Me.Controls("TextBoxs" & j).Value = rFound.Offset(0, j -1).Value
            Next j

            ' load the image into the image holder
            ' rFound.Row is the row where we need to look for the data
             Set shImage = GetImage(rFound.Row)
             If Not shImage Is Nothing Then
                 ' valid image found
                 shImage.Copy
                 Set Image1.Picture = PastePicture(xlPicture)
             End If
         Else
            ClearForm bAll:=False ' keep text in textbox1
         End If
     End With

    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    ' IM STUCKED FROM HERE
    '----------------------------------------------------------------       

    Set wsData2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Stock Update")
    With wsData2
        ' Get the item number in sID
        sID = Me.TextBoxs1.Value

        ' check column A of the datasheet for the entry
        Set rFound = Columns("A").Find(what:=sID, _
                                    after:=.Cells(1, 1))
        ' if found, process. else quit
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then ' This checks that rFound is set to an 
                                        object and not 'nothing'

            ' Load the details in the text boxes
            TextBoxs12.Value = rFound.Offset(0, 3).Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[Page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9mNj.jpg)

[Page2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8mmK.jpg)

Comment: so what is the error you are getting?

Comment: im not getting any error.. its just that the data is populated from only active sheet. 
For example lets say textbox12 should show data from sheet4 A1 but its showing data from sheet1(active sheet) A1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
Set rFound = Columns("A").Find(what:=sID, after:=.Cells(1, 1))
```

refers to the active sheet's column A. If you want it to refer to WsData1's column A you must precede the column reference with a period, like `.Columns("A").Find`. With that done, you can use the same setup you have on any datasheet you specify.